# Add row dynamically in listview with blank edittext

Tags: android, listview

I want to show a listview with a blank edittext at first and then to add new blank edittexts on button click. Right now edittext gets added but any data which I add to these blank edittexts get removed when I add a new edittext. Also when I delete an item, all the data get removed from the remaining edittexts.

```js
// row layout

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/delImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

```css
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button openBtn;
    ArrayList<Model> listItems=new ArrayList<Model>();
    ContactsListAdapter adapter;
    int resource;
    ListView list;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        openBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openBtn);

        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new ContactsListAdapter(this, resource, listItems);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        openBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addItems();
            }
        });


    }

    public void addItems() {
        Model model = new Model();
        model.setCount(listItems.size()+1);
        listItems.add(model);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }




}
```

```html
public class ContactsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private Context mContext;
    int resource;
    private ArrayList<Model> arrayList = new ArrayList<Model>();

    public ContactsListAdapter(Context mContext, int resource, ArrayList<Model> arrayList) {
        super(mContext, resource, arrayList);
        this.resource = resource;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();

            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false);

            holder.myEt  = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.myEt);
            holder.delImg = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.delImg);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        final Model item = arrayList.get(position);

        holder.myEt.setText(item.getName());

        holder.delImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                arrayList.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });



        return v;
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        EditText myEt;
        ImageView delImg;
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't save those EditTexts values anywhere, so no wonder it's not restored on reuse of the view

Comment: Can I use textwatcher to save the text into model when user types on the edittext ?

Comment: yes, and inside the textwatcher you can update corresponding object inside the listItems

Comment: Looks like its working now. Thanks.